# Flexslider alignment of <li>

Tags: html, css, flexslider

Hi everyone i am using a `flexslider` widget in my application and problem with that is the alignment as i am rotating product listing of 2 item at a time.

So when i run it initially it is not aligned properly on the page

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dw10pmut/) of that

Please tell me what can i do to align it properly.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above it doesnt display 2 products properly on the page

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the margin on `.single-wid-product` that is giving you issues. I changed it to padding and it works for me as expected:

```
.single-wid-product {
    padding-bottom: 31px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dw10pmut/1/